# Bootstrap Form Validation Plugin Recommendation

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone recommend a good (and free) form validation plugin for using with Bootstrap.

I've been using the form found here: https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator - But it's limited in which is doesnt support validation on textareas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Comment: That looks good hurricane ... I'll take a look at that.